# What is this service called in English?

Tags: networking, web-hosting, dedicated-server

**DETAILS**

I'm not familiar with server administration and am trying to find the name of a particular service offered by a Japanese website provider. The service is for a dedicated server. I have attached a picture detailing the service below.

The **left side** of the picture shows the server **without** the service.

The **right side** shows the server **with** the service.

Once I know the name of the service I will Google it, but any additional information in regards to the pros and cons of such a service would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**QUESTION**

- What is the name of the service in the picture.
- What are the pros and cons of this service?

[image: available service for dedicated servers]

Comment: It looks like some type of load balancing or multi-WAN HA to me.

Comment: While the answers provided *may* be correct, I'm not sure if they are... why don't you link to the service offering and let us take a look to be sure?

Comment: Here it is http://server.sakura.ad.jp/dedicated/gn.html I feel pretty stupid now, because on reading it again I can clearly see that it says VLAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it could be describing VLAN:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN

Comment: Looks a bit like OVH's 'virtual rack' service http://www.ovh.co.uk/dedicated_servers/virtual_rack.xml

Answer (score 2):

Its some sort of network segregation so that groups of servers are separated and cannot connect to each other.

It could be done using VLANs or by separate physical switches